# ASP.NET Redirect to other page internal

Tags: asp.net, redirect, routes, httpmodule

Is there a way to redirect a asp.net page to another and restart the server workflow without the user seeing it in their browser?

1. Call to .NET Page (handled by routing)
2. Perform some actions based on this call
3. Call other webpage internal (handled by a httpmodule)

The internal page don't "exist" (passes though a module that performs some routing) so I don't think a simple Server.Transfer will work.

Answer (score 1):

You Two Option First you User Jquery and you can Poast data to another page without changes in browser and second is that you can use  Cross Page posting. In Cross Page Posting you can call another page from base page. And you can access all data of base to that page.
[Follow this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx).

Comment: I should have said the the serverside does not have any js enabled.

Comment: so you can use CrossPageposting.